# Scrapy crawler what tells me this output?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

My scrapy test code is the following. I tested it via scrapy shell and it worked. But now if I finally started to write a script no output appears. Is there something wrong? Thanks.

my code so far:

```
import scrapy


class CryptohunterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cryptohunter"
    start_urls=["https://www.coingecko.com/de"]



def parse(self, response):

    for x in response.xpath('//div[@class="coin-content center"]/a/span/text()'):
        print (x.extract())
```

Output:
[image]
Sorry I couldn't input the shell, so I started a screenshot.

So I'm not sure if it's the error or not. If it should be an error, how show I handle it?

[image]
How to get the full number out of this?
It's always rounded by 2.
Output: 0,07 instead of 0.0688852511227967

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation in Python is very important ([more info about indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html)).

Incorrect indentation can cause errors or wrong program execution. In your case `parse()` method does not belong to your class. So during execution `scrapy` tries to find `parse()` method in `CryptohunterSpider` and fails with error:

```
raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
```

You need to properly indent your code so `parse()` belongs to the class

```
import scrapy

class CryptohunterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cryptohunter"
    start_urls=["https://www.coingecko.com/de"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for x in response.xpath('//div[@class="coin-content center"]/a/span/text()'):
            print ("Extract: ", x.extract())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the explanation. Its a horrible mistake that i couldnt identifiy.

Comment: I also cant understand why i need to start the crawler within the scrapy shell. All other options doesnt work.

Comment: Is there a way to get not rounded numbers with srapy? My output is always rounded by two diggits after the comma. How to prevent scrapy to not round the ouptut.
Output: 0,07
real Ouptut:0,06885...